# How can my Obj-C GUI app open my .Net Xamarin.IOS GUI app?

Tags: .net, objective-c, xamarin.ios

I would like my ObjC GUI app to programmatically launch/open my .Net Xamarin.IOS GUI app.
How can I do it?

These are all in-house, non-app-store apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean want Xcode builded iOS App to open a Xamarin iOS App , you can use **[openURL](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace/3172701-openurl?language=occ)** to open another iOS App . No matter it builds from Xcode or Xamarin, you just need to set the **URL Schemes** in `info.plist` file.

For example , setting in Xamarin iOS :

[image]

Then Xcode iOS App open it :

```
- (IBAction)OpenXamariniOSApp:(id)sender{

    if(@available(iOS10.0, *)) {    

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"XamariniOS://"] options:@{} completionHandler:nil];            

    }else{                 

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"XamariniOS://"]];

    }
}
```

The effect :(first time Apple will popup a window)

[image]

Comment: Great!  How do I do it without the popup "..wants to open" ?

Comment: I get build error "..ios expected a version of the form major minor subminor.."  for line with "if(@available(iOS10.0..."

Comment: Hey, it worked!  And there was no popup like in your animated example above.  And, I solved the build error by simply deleted the "...@available...." line.

Comment: QUESTION: How does ObjC app know path to XamariniOS app?

Comment: @DougNull You could see my answer that using **URL Schemes** can find the app installed in iPhone, it is designed by Apple for every iOS App. No matter what the app is based on Xamarin.iOS or Native iOS.